# Me being a Automation Tester (QA), how can I win a Ideathon? What should I develop for Ideathon?

Tags: automated-testing, java, browser-automation

I have over 9 years of experience in Automation. Still, I think my Java coding skills are limited.

Having said that, if I target to win Ideathon 2019, what should I develop?

Comment: Not all subjective questions are poor questions, but you should read [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and reevaluate this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *very subjective* question and therefore, my answer will be *very subjective*...

First, I think you need to ask yourself some questions:

1. What is the coolest thing I have done in those 9 years?
2. Did I do this cool thing to the best of my abilities?
3. What is my target audience for this idea?
4. Who is my 'customer'?
5. What is the scope of this particular Ideathon?
6. What is the most annoying part of my job, and how can I fix that?

I have never participated in an Ideathon but, I know that, for my personality, I am always looking to simplify my approach to everything in my life.  To find a better way of doing things; no matter what it is.  Some suggestions I could give you would be:

1. Could you possibly build a library of common functions that you would use in a `POM` perhaps?
2. Could you possibly come up with a solution that handles deprecated/to-be-deprecated classes in `Selenium` like the `PageFactory`?

The long and the short here, is simply that **you** are the only one that can really determine whether you win it or not.  Regardless of the outcome, I wish you the best!